# How can I add a button select to a case statement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I already have the button event handlers.But i don't know of a property on the `btn_click` event so that when I select a button,i can uniquely identify them

```
   private void buttonSelect()
   { 

   switch(GlobalVariables.buttonSets){
        case 0:
           button click event here
           break;
        case 1:
           second button click event here
           break;          
           }
    }
```

Comment: you should know the `button` from the `button_click` event handler?

Comment: The sender argument is the Button_Click event, is the button that is clicked

Answer (score 3):

That is the wrong way around. When you click a button, that button should call a specific, correctly-named method:

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessage();
}

private void SendMessage()
{
    // message sending logic here
}
```

Now when you want to send a message without clicking a button, just call `SendMessage()` from code.

Comment: No, because there is one button that needs to fire two events.

Comment: @user2122032 only one click-event can be handled by a button.You're not talking about radiobuttons, are you?

Answer (score 0):

very confusing, in the post you are mentioning that there are two buttons that you want to identify which one is clicked

for this you u need to call your method in both button click and send some specific parameter to that method

but 
at the first answer you mentioning that there is only one button that needs to fire two events,

but you have not mentioned what are the conditions for those events to fire.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the following code you can get which button is clicked.

```
(sender as Button).Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the case statement:

```
switch( ButtonSelected )
        {

            case 0:
                //Edit selected

                break;
            case 1:
                //Save selected

                break;
        }

        if( ButtonSelected == 0 ) {

            UpdateResidentInformation();


        }
        if( ButtonSelected == 1 ) {

            AddResidentInformation();

        }
    }
```